# JQuery Abrir modal y pasar datos extraidos de consulta Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente formulario en el que leo un código de barras. Con la funcion `checkcb()` verifico el codigo de barras y busco la referencia a la que corresponde, devolviendo el codigo del articulo (es una select a la bbdd)

```js
function checkcb() {
 var codbarras = $("#pidecodbar").val();
        if(codbarras != ""){
          var dataString = 'codbar=' + codbarras;
  jQuery.ajax({
  url: "verifica_codbar.php",
  data: dataString,
  type: "POST",
  success:function(data){
             var cod_art = $.trim(data);
             $('#PESO').find('input[name="articulo"]').val(cod_art);   
             $('#PESO').modal('show');
  },
  error:function (){}
  });
 }
}
```

```html
<div class='form-group'>
  <div class='col-xs-12'>
   <h5 class='bg-info text-center'><span>CODIGO DE BARRAS</span></h5>
    <input type='text' name='pidecodbar' id='pidecodbar' onchange='checkcb()' value='' class='form-control input-sm' required>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='modal fade' id='PESO' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='PedirPeso' aria-hidden='true'>
  <div class='modal-dialog'>
   <div class='modal-content'>
    <div class='modal-header'>
     <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>";
    <h3 class='modal-title' id='PedirPeso'><span class='label label-success'>ENTRADA MERCANCIA</span></h3>
   </div>
    <div class='modal-body'>
      <form name='pidepeso' id='pidepeso' action='' method='post' class='form-horizontal' role='form'>";
        <div class='form-group'>
          <div class='col-xs-12'>
         <span><u>Ref.</u>: </span><input type='text' size='10' name='articulo' class='text-muted' readonly>
         </div>
        </div>
          <div class='form-group'>
            <div class='col-xs-6'>";
           <h5 class='bg-primary text-center'><span>PESO BRUTO</span></h5>
                <input type='number' step='0.01' name='pesobruto' id='pesobruto' value='' class='form-control input-sm' required>
            </div>
          </div>
        <input name='submitpeso' type='submit' class='btn btn-danger' value='GRABAR'>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class='modal-footer'>
       <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Cerrar</button>
     </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

El problema es que no consigo que el input `articulo` del modal tenga el valor que me devuelve la consulta Ajax (`cod_art`), y al mostrar el modal me aparece el input vacío.

¿donde me estoy equivocando?

---

Ya he solucionado el problema de input en el modal, simplemente tenía que abrir antes el modal y luego pasarle el valor.

```js
$('#PESO').modal('show');
$('#PESO').find('input[name="articulo"]').val(cod_art);
```

Ahora el problema que tengo es con el input text. Por ejemplo, si salgo del foco del input con la tecla TAB, funciona bien, pero si pulso ENTER no funciona y sale por la funcion ERROR de Ajax. ¿alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Te recomendaria darle un id a tu input y targetear el input usando este id en lugar de la propiedad "name". Igualmente prueba a hacer console.logs() para asegurarte que estas recibiendo el dato correcto y que el elemento de jQuery es el correcto.

Comment: Hola @narshe. He comprobado que `cod_art` recibe el dato correctamente, pero no me aparece en el modal en el campo input `articulo`. :-(

Comment: Ya probaste si el valor viene en data.d ?

Comment: El valor viene correcto por `data`, pero si salgo del foco con la tecla TAB. Si salgo con INTRO, no viene el valor y sale siempre por la funcion error de Ajax. ¿alguna idea?